# Receiving HTML-encoded values from asp.net mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm fairly new to MVC web api, and trying to get POST requests to process properly. It's mostly working, but string values are HTML-encoded. I thought this would be handled automatically, and I find no way to do this manually.

Here is the ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/PulseStudies/UpdateTask',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'userID': userid, 'taskID': CurExamTaskID, 'comment': comment, 'complete': complete },
        async: true,
...
```

Here is the server-side API:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateTask(TaskResponse value)
{
    Tasks.UpdateTask(value.userID, value.taskID, value.comment, value.complete);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}

public class TaskResponse
{
    public int userID { get; set; }
    public long taskID { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public bool complete { get; set; }
}
```

The comment value is HTML-encoded, e.g., "blah%20blah". How do I get a properly decoded value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean it is UrlEncoded.  On the server side you want HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt(v=vs.110).aspx to get it back.